# $urlRouterProvider when() match any slug in URL?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I’m attempting to go to a specific state using the $urlRouterProvider’s `when` function.

The pattern I wish to match is a slug of any name directly after the base url. Like so:

http://baseurl.com/any-slug-name

Here’s what I have tried:

I first tested this to see if it worked as it expected:

```
myApp.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$urlRouterProvider
 .when('/shoe', ['$state', function ($state) {
        $state.go(‘foot');
  }])
 .otherwise('/');

 .state('foot', {
      url: '/foot',
      ...
  })
 });
```

And it did. But what I want is this:

```
$urlRouterProvider
     .when(‘/Any-Slug-On-Base-Url', ['$state',function ($state) {
             $state.go(’theState');
     }])
     .otherwise('/');

      .state('theState', {
           url: '/theState',
           ...
      })
 });
```

How can I achieve this?

I Feel I’ll achieve what I want using a regex in the `what` parameter but not sure how to implement it.